# transform library project in jar (android)

Tags: android, plugins, jar, import, android-source

I need to import into my Eclipse project an external library that is given under the project "Library." this: https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh 
how do I turn the "Library" folder in a file. jar that I can put in my libs folder?

Answer (score 1):

> how do I turn the "Library" folder in a file. jar that I can put in my libs folder?

First, that is an Android library project. It depends upon Android resources. It cannot be a JAR.

Second, that is an Android library project set up for use with Gradle and Android Studio. It is not set up for Eclipse users, and the author of the library did not provide Eclipse instructions.

Third, as it says **IN REALLY BIG BOLD LETTERS**, the project is discontinued.

You will be better served [using `SwipeRefreshLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SwipeRefreshLayout.html) (from the Android Support libraries), or possibly [the PullToRefresh-ListView open source project](https://github.com/erikwt/PullToRefresh-ListView).

You are welcome to reorganize the code from that Gradle project (the "Library" folder you referred to) into an Eclipse project, moving the Java source under `src/` and the resources under `res/` and try to get it working. However, you will have to use it as an [Android library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject), not a JAR.

Comment: Only then you can build it and take the jar out of the /bin folder.